# Run MATLAB executable from Python

Tags: python, matlab, subprocess, executable

I am trying to run a MATLAB executable (main.exe) from Python. main.exe file was generated using the .m files in my project, using the application compiler.
To run the executable from Python, I tried

```
import subprocess

cmd = r"C:/Windows/System32/cmd I:/sim/main/main.exe"
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=0x08000000)
process.wait()
```

But this doesn't generate the output file.
In MATLAB's command prompt, when I run the executable  (!main) output is saved in the results folder in 50 secs.
But the output file isn't generated while running from Python.

Suggestions on how to run the executable in Python will be really helpful.

Comment: Are you collecting and examining possible error messages generated when trying to run this process? Have you tried running the executable from the system shell? What OS are you using?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, thanks a lot for the reply. I am using Windows 10.  While running from python, I don't see any error message.

Comment: try use `cmd = r"cmd I:/sim/main/main.exe > output.file"`

Comment: But are you looking for the error messages? Where does `stderr` go? Did you try running the executable from outside Python, at the system shell (command prompt)?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes. When I run it directly from cmd, I navigate to  the folder `I:/sim/main/` and type main.exe in the cmd. This doesn't throw any error and the output is also saved in the respective folder without any issue. Also, I don't specify the output file name (main.exe > output.file) in the cmd. I only run the executable.

Comment: @ganz Thank you, I tried that and unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Ok. So maybe also switch directory in Python before running the program?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I moved the .py file which runs the executable to the same folder where main.exe is saved. Then I replaced `cmd = r"C:/Windows/System32/cmd I:/sim/main/main.exe"` with `r"C:/Windows/System32/cmd main.exe`.  The output file isn't generated :( . I'm not sure if it would be a problem if the MATLAB plots aren't supressed. When I run in cmd, MATLAB plot window opens and results are also saved. In python, I am not sure if MATLAB plot window could be a problem; unfortunately , I don't see any error message.

Comment: Again, you’re not recording `stderr`, I think it might be suppressed? That is where error messages would go.

Answer (score 0):

```html
import subprocess

# Set the path to the MATLAB executable
matlab_executable = r"C:/Windows/System32/cmd I:/sim/main/main.exe"

# Run the executable and capture the output
result = subprocess.run(matlab_executable, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# Print the output
print(result.stdout)
print(result.stderr)
```